# Rotation works but without animation

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I am using this code to rotate a an image

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
                    self.myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * CGFloat(Double.pi)) / 180.0)
            })
```

the image rotate but without any animation. Do you have an idea about the problem?

Comment: [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; add this line inside animation and its work

Comment: where shall I add it exactly?

Comment: Your code works fine here. Make sure there are no fighting constrains set to `myImageView`.

Comment: UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {
        self.myImageView.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * CGFloat(Double.pi)) / 180.0))
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })

Its working fine

Comment: self.myImageView.layer.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * CGFloat(Double.pi)) / 180.0)